# Adding ngx-translate to angular-seed results in errors during aot build execution

Tags: angular, angular-seed, ngx-translate

I added [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate) to my [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) project. Running it normally (`npm start`) or on production build (`npm run build.prod`) works fine. Running aot build using `npm run build.prod.aot` results in errors during execution.
An error log of the console is shown below:

[image]

I have created a fork with a minimal reproduction of the problem: https://github.com/kubica/angular-seed. Also look [at this commit](https://github.com/kubica/angular-seed/commit/5c5c8d33d63cca1f3ea048f0e14b9989192f0f91) to check if i missed something.

The [angular-seed-advances](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) project contains ngx-translate, too and the aot build works without any trouble but i could not figure out what's the exactly difference.

Anybody got an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get this to working?

Comment: I don't know why but i finally got it working with aot + rollup (`npm run build.prod.rollup.aot`). Without rollup it's still crashing